# online and offline machine learning representation in MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

what is the difference between offline and online learning considering that the program will be made with matlab .. and please check the following matlab code , does it fall into one of those two categories?

```
function y = Perceptron_online(inputs,dest,iterations,Bias)
w = rand(1,size(inputs,2));
i=0;
while (i<iterations)
    output = sum(w.*inputs)+ Bias;
    if sign(output)~=sign(dest)
        diffW = dest.*inputs;
        w = w + diffW;
        diffBias = dest;
        Bias = Bias + diffBias;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
y=output;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

- in Online machine learning data becomes available in a sequential order and is used to update the predictor (its parameters) for future data at each step
- (as instead) in Offline machine learning we generate the best predictor by learning on the entire training data set at once

Such code looks like a Perceptron, which can be used in online classification but you should specify what `input` and `output` are.
If `input` is the data matrix and `output` is the known labels vector, you can work in an online fashion by removing the iterations and simply scanning the data matrix, that is (for every *j*th example):

1. evaluate output
2. update weights

However if you want to work in an offline fashion you can repeat such steps until a maximum number of iterations has been reached or until the iteration error is less then a specific, a priori known, threshold.